# How to write C++ code to fit within LaTeX listings margins

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, emacs, latex

I'm using the `listings` package in LaTeX to include source code, but some of my source code runs off to the right and so some lines are obviously too long.  Does anyone know if there is a way to mark the margin when I'm writing the code, perhaps depending on the `\setlength` parameters I set in my LaTeX environment so that I know to stop there?  I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and TeXworks for this particular problem, but I often just use Emacs to write both C++ code and LaTeX.

Here's a snippet from LaTeX I'm using:

```
\lstdefinestyle{C++}
    {float=h!, frame=single, language={[Visual]C++}, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, tabsize=2}

\lstinputlisting[style=C++, label=lst:RANDU, caption=RANDU C++ Implementation]{RANDU.cpp}
```

Here's a snippet of what the output of this looks like, I'd like to know where to end lines in my IDE so that it doesn't exceed the right border:

[image: PDF of problem code]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been flagged for migration to [tex.se].

Comment: @Werner That's fine.  I had it posted there originally but no one was biting.  Not much better here, though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use packages like [fill-column-indicator](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator) or [column-enforce-mode](https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode).  Both available also with MELPA.

The downside is that you will need to manually update the number of columns you want when you update your \setlength, unless you write some code to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `breaklines=true` in the options. Example:

```
\lstdefinestyle{C++}
    {
        float=h!, frame=single, language={[Visual]C++}, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, tabsize=2, breaklines=true
    }
```